# Assets php error undefined index

Tags: assets

I'm getting these PHP errors with Assets 2.05 installed in EE 2.5.5. When an uploaded image is edited through the File Manager "Edit File" or "Edit Image" actions, these warnings show:

Undefined index: upload_location_id
Filename: assets/ext.assets.php
Line Number: 255

Undefined index: file_name
Filename: assets/ext.assets.php
Line Number: 255

Undefined index: upload_location_id
Filename: assets/ext.assets.php
Line Number: 260

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/curvedes/public_html/mercytouch2/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 809

The image shows up properly in Assets, indexing shows all the upload folders, which have their preferences set to 777.

If I uninstall Assets, the errors disappear. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hey Brian.  A few questions.  Are you using S3, Local sources, or both?  And is the Assets extension showing as enabled, and you have extensions also generally enabled?

Comment: Hi Lisa. I'm using only local sources. Assets extension is enabled, showing ver 2.0.5, and standard extensions for ee are enabled. Everything is working, apart from the errors that show up using FM "Edit File" or "Edit Image."

Comment: Brian, can you walk me, step by step, through getting to that error?  Upload a file using Assets (on the publish page?) and then....  Thank you!

Comment: 1. In Assets, select upload and browse to image file
2. Upload appears in Assets file manager in correct upload directory
3. Chose EE File manager, uploaded file is visible, shows thumbnail, correct upload directory location
4. Under Actions in FIle manager window, click on pencil icon and view Edit FIle
5. Either do nothing or enter into Description a line of text
6. Click Save, and error messages show.

Comment: The same errors appear when choosing "Edit Image", and it doesn't matter if an edit is made or not. Hitting Save in the edit window triggers the errors.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I'm going to try to reproduce this over the weekend and I'll let you know what I find out.  The step by step helped a lot!

Comment: Brian, my fault entirely, I totally dropped this.  I will be testing this tonight/tomorrow morning, and will update then.

Comment: I'm having this problem, too. After a little digging, it has to do with the fact that EE calls file_after_save hook not only when uploading a new file, but also when editing (crop/resize/rotate) an image. When *editing* an image, the $data that gets passed as the 2nd param to the hook call does NOT contain the same data as when an upload is made. Rather, it has a file_id and some image height/width info. I have patched my own copy of Assets with a fix, you paste this section in at the top of your file_after_save function in ext.assets.php. https://gist.github.com/rsanchez/d277fdcca7bdff385c4a

Comment: Rob, I tried this and found that a closing } was needed to get it working, just before line 45: $query->free_result();
However, in edit mode, if an image is flipped hor or vert, the file won't save in Assets for me, even though the edit preview shows that it was altered. Rotating and flipping does save and shows in Assets thumbnails. Thanks for the patch code, now at least the php errors are absent. @LisaWess